# Pass custom run name in dbutils.notebook.run()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, optimization, databricks, jobs

I am running a notebook using `dbutils.notebook.run()` method.
The notebook is getting executed perfectly.

But, I want that instead of `Untitled run` some other text should be used as run name.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvy5g.png)

Is it possible to achieve this?
Is yes then how??
For now I am using this code to run the notebook:

```
dbutils.notebook.run(file_name, 36000, eval(params),
                        _NotebookHandler__databricks_internal_cluster_spec=cluster_config)
```